# How to design SQL database properly

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have two tables

The first table:

Table "public.things"

```
Column  | Type                   | Collation | Nullable |  Default
--------+------------------------+-----------+----------+----------
id      | bigint                 |           | not null |
name    | character varying(255) |           | not null |     
slug    | character varying(255) |           |          |   
lang_id | integer                |           |          |
```

Indexes:

- "things_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
- "things_slug_unique" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (slug)

The second table for store many to many for regions and things:

Table "public.values"

```
Column     |  Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  
-----------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+--------
thing_id   | bigint |           | not null |         | plain                 
region_id  | bigint |           | not null |         | plain                 
values     | jsonb  |           | not null |         | extended
```

Indexes:

- "values_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (thing_id, region_id)

And I have the third table which should store users variants from table **values**

Polymorphic table **user_variants** looks like:

Table "public.user_variants"

```
Column       |  Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default |  
-------------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+
user_id      | int    |           | not null |         |  
entity_id    | bigint |           | not null |         |              
entity_type  | bigint |           | not null |         |              
content      | jsonb  |           | not null |         |
```

For example, I can store in **user_variants** table something like this:

```
 user_id |  entity_id  | entity_type    | content              |
---------+-------------+----------------+----------------------+
 41      | 23          |  combination_1 | '{ values: [ ...] }' |                    
 42      | 24          |  combination_2 | '{ values: [ ...] }' |
```

I have the problem, my table **values** does not have a unique **id** for storing in **entity_id** field, but table values has primary key **"values_pkey"** consists of **thing_id, region_id**. How can I without adding "id" to my **values** table, use exists primary key **"values_pkey"**?

Comment: Does your table `user_variants` have a foreign key that points to `values`? If so, you should have this FK in there, instead of `entity_id`.

Comment: @TheImpaler table `user_variants` is universal and implies that I can store any values in field entity_id, and so I can't constraint `user_variants.entity_id`

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. What does '"use existing primary key "values_pkey"' mean?--Use it to do what? 'constraint user_variants.entity_id"'--constrain it in what way? Explain what the constraints/limits are on possible DB states--simultaneous table values. PS Clarifiy via edits, not commments. PS Your presentation would be clearer & easier to talk about & answer if you just gave the DDL & tabular executable initialization code for example values, instead of all those words & metadata tables.

Comment: Are you trying to constrain column entity_id in table user_variants in some way? If so, say so, and say what way. Etc.